# JSON: Should string value 0 be in quotes or not?

Tags: json

I need to return some JSON string from my server to end user, where there is a field which is documented to be a string, but the field's value is always a number, so must I always return it as:

```
{"attr": "99"}
```

or is this also valid:

```
{"attr": 99}
```

Client is complaining that I should put 99 in quotations as it is documented to be a string, and their parser will parse the number 99 to a number type which creates problem.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Since "..is documented to be a string", then *use a string*.

*Strings* (e.g. "99") and *numbers* (e.g. 99) are [*two different kinds of values*](http://www.json.org/) in JSON.

Some consumers can automatically convert between strings and numbers when de-serializing while others cannot - in this case it appears "cannot" or "will not". Since an external API was specified, it should be honored. At least then if it doesn't work it's not your code breaking ;-)

Comment: I agree with this post in that if the client API documents the parameter as a string they may have their reason from a backend perspective, and you should stick to the requirements. For example you may be dealing with just numbers now but the client has plans to implement characters soon and you would be in trouble then.

Comment: @JoeMinichino A very good point. The API publisher may have additional reasons for requiring (and only accepting) a string value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a guarantee that it is always a number, and you want it to be treated as a number, unquote it.  If it is either possible to get a non-numeric value, or you want it treated as a string, leave it quoted.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quoted. Client expects string values and this is explicitly documented, so does not make sense counteract.